# $G$ is non-abelian and satisfies $(ab)^2=(ba)^2 , \forall a,b \in G$

Tags: group-theory

It is known that if a finite group of odd order satisfies $(ab)^2=(ba)^2 , \forall a,b \in G$ , then $G$ is abelian . I am looking for examples where

(i) $G$ is infinite , non-abelian and satisfies $(ab)^2=(ba)^2 , \forall a,b \in G$

(ii) $G$ is finite of even order , non-abelian and satisfies $(ab)^2=(ba)^2 , \forall a,b \in G$

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(ii) The group $D_4$. If $ab$ is a reflection, then so is $ba$ and both squares are the identity. If $ab$ is a $\pm90^°$ rotation, then so is $ba$ and both squares are the rotation by $180^°$.

(i) Take $D_4\oplus \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Is $D_4$ infinite? Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: $D_4\oplus \mathbb Z$ is infinite

Comment: Oh, (i) and (ii) were reversed. Sorry for being confused.